# How to troubleshoot a cron job in Jupyterlab's scheduler?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

Dears,

Here is the situation:
["error submitting the job"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLatv.png)

I have anaconda installed alongside Jupyterlab. Before installing the extension (jupyterlab_scheduler), i made sure to install crontab and node.js, as requested.

The jupyter notebook to print is just one line of code with: `print("hello world")`

Any ideas how I could find the source of the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? What are the logs in the console? Have you tried the things mentioned in https://github.com/tiburon-security/jupyterlab_scheduler/issues/15?

Comment: I don't know how to make it more clear than this. I'm trying to schedule a cron job, but it won't work and I have no idea where to look as there are not many threads about this.

Also I'm running the job directly from the jupyterlab extension, without going through the console. 

I will try and learn to run it from the console to access the logs.

Comment: Hello again. So, being stuck where I was, i basically gave up (still no iea what went awry). I went for another solution which was using windows's task scheduler and it worked! For those interested, here is a link explaining the steps: https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/. I hope this helps.